Redux Perist is not storing Data
#store
import {  combineReducers, configureStore } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import { persistReducer, persistStore } from "redux-persist";
import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-async-storage/async-storage';
import addUserSlice, { signInUser } from "./slices/addUserSlice";
import { thunk } from "redux-thunk";

const persistConfig = {
    key: 'root',
    storage: AsyncStorage,
    whitelist:['addUser']
}


const persistedReducer = persistReducer(persistConfig,addUserSlice)
export const store = configureStore(
    {
       reducer: persistedReducer,
       middleware: (getDefaultMiddleware) => getDefaultMiddleware({
        immutableCheck: false,
        serializableCheck: false,
      })      

    }
);
export const persistor = persistStore(store)

#slice
import { createSlice } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";


export const addUserSlice = createSlice({
    name:'addUser',
    initialState:{
        userData:[]
    },

    reducers:{
        signupUser:(state, action)=>{

            console.log("adduser slice-----", action.payload) 
            state.userData.push(action.payload)

        },
        signInUser:(state, action)=>{
            const {username, password} = action.payload
            return state.filter(item=>item.username===username && item.password ===password)
        }

    }
})

export const { signupUser, signInUser } = addUserSlice.actions; 
export default addUserSlice.reducer

i was trying to store data in AsyncStorage using Redux-Persist and redux Toolkit. But no data is storing in async stoarge. i need to store the data in async storage so, it should not loss if refresh

The whitelist config only work one level deep. If you want to persist the addUser state slice, you should create a persisted reducer on the root reducer. You can use combineReducers function to create the root reducer.
store.ts:
import { combineReducers, configureStore } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';
import { persistReducer, persistStore } from 'redux-persist';
import storage from 'redux-persist/lib/storage';
import addUserSliceReducer from './addUserSlice';

const persistConfig = {
  key: 'root',
  storage,
  whitelist: ['addUser'],
};

const rootReducer = combineReducers({
  addUser: addUserSliceReducer,
});

const persistedReducer = persistReducer(persistConfig, rootReducer);

export const store = configureStore({
  reducer: persistedReducer,
  middleware: (getDefaultMiddleware) =>
    getDefaultMiddleware({
      immutableCheck: false,
      serializableCheck: false,
    }),
});
export const persistor = persistStore(store);

Persisted state in local storage:

stackblitz

TypeError: 0, _$$_REQUIRE(_dependencyMap9slices/addUserSlice").signupUser is not a function (it is undefined), js engine: hermes

@PrajwalVK Please check the code on stackblitz. It works fine.

import {  combineReducers, configureStore } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import { persistReducer, persistStore } from "redux-persist";
import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-async-storage/async-storage';
import addUserSlice, { signInUser } from "./slices/addUserSlice";
import { thunk } from "redux-thunk";

const persistConfig = {
    key: 'root',
    storage: AsyncStorage,
    whitelist:['addUser']
}


const persistedReducer = persistReducer(persistConfig,addUserSlice)
export const store = configureStore(
    {
       reducer: persistedReducer,
       middleware: (getDefaultMiddleware) => getDefaultMiddleware({
        immutableCheck: false,
        serializableCheck: false,
      })      

    }
);
export const persistor = persistStore(store)

#slice
import { createSlice } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";


export const addUserSlice = createSlice({
    name:'addUser',
    initialState:{
        userData:[]
    },

    reducers:{
        signupUser:(state, action)=>{

            console.log("adduser slice-----", action.payload) 
            state.userData.push(action.payload)

        },
        signInUser:(state, action)=>{
            const {username, password} = action.payload
            return state.filter(item=>item.username===username && item.password ===password)
        }

    }
})

export const { signupUser, signInUser } = addUserSlice.actions; 
export default addUserSlice.reducer

You need to wrap persistor and store into app.js file like :
import {LogBox, Platform, SafeAreaView} from 'react-native';
import AppProvider from './src/context/AppProvider';
import RootNavigator from './src/navigation/rootNavigator';
import Toast from 'react-native-toast-message';
import {Provider} from 'react-redux';
import {PersistGate} from 'redux-persist/integration/react';
import {persistor, store} from './src/redux/store';
import {LogLevel, OneSignal} from 'react-native-onesignal';
import {setUserData} from './src/utils/user.util';
import {updateUserData} from './src/services/firebase.service';
function App(): JSX.Element {
 

  return (
    <Provider store={store}>
      <PersistGate loading={null} persistor={persistor}>
        <SafeAreaView style={{flex: 1, backgroundColor: 'white'}}>
          <AppProvider>
            <RootNavigator />
          </AppProvider>
          <Toast />
        </SafeAreaView>
      </PersistGate>
    </Provider>
  );
}

export default App;




import { Alert, KeyboardAvoidingView, SafeAreaView, StyleSheet, Text, TextInput, TouchableOpacity, View } from 'react-native'
import React, { useContext, useEffect, useState } from 'react'
import styles from './style'
import { KeyboardAwareScrollView } from 'react-native-keyboard-aware-scroll-view'
import ListModal from '../../components/Modal'
import { CountryDataContextAPI } from '../../context/CountryDataContext'
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from 'react-redux'
import addUserSlice, { signupUser } from '../../redux/slices/addUserSlice'

export default function Signup({ navigation, page, route, user }) {

  const [countryData, setCountryData] = useState("")
  const [countryId, setCountryId] = useState()
  const [stateData, setStateData] = useState("")
  const { location, setLocation } = useContext(CountryDataContextAPI);
  const dispatch = useDispatch()

  const [confirmPassword, setConfirmPassword] = useState('')
  const getCountryId = () => {
    if (countryData) {
      setCountryId(countryData.id)
    }
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    getCountryId()
    // console.log(countryId)
  }, [countryData])
  // console.log(user?[0].name, "countrydata");
  // console.log(route,'aa')


  const [userData, setUserData] = useState({
    name: "",
    username: "",
    mobile: "",
    email: "",
    addres: "",
    country: countryData.name,
    state: stateData.name,
    password: ""
  })
  // console.log(navigation)
  const setData = () => {
    // setUserData((prev) => { ({ ...prev, country: location.country.name, state: location.state.name }) })
    setUserData(prev => ({ ...prev, country: location?.country?.name, state: location.state.name }))
  }
  useEffect(() => {
    setData()
  }, [location])

  const handleSignup = () => {

    const { name, username, mobile, email, password, state, country, addres } = userData

    if (!name || !username || !mobile || !email || !password || !country || !addres) {
      Alert.alert("please fill the form completely")
    }
    else {
      if (mobile.length < 0 || mobile.length < 10) {
        Alert.alert("Invalid Mobile number")
      }
      else {
        const regeX = new RegExp(/^[a-z0-9]+@[a-z]+\.[a-z]{2,3}$/)
        const regeXPwd = new RegExp('^(?=.*?[A-Z])(?=.*?[a-z])(?=.*?[0-9])(?=.*?[#?!@$%^&*-]).{8,}$')
        if (regeX.test(email)) {
          if (regeXPwd.test(password)) {
            if (confirmPassword === password) {
              dispatch(signupUser(userData));
              navigation.navigate('Login', {
                username: userData.username,
                password: userData.password
              })
            }
            else {
              Alert.alert("Please check the password")
            }
          }
          else {
            Alert.alert("Password must contain atleast one Uppercase letter,smaller case letter , Number and One special charactor")
          }
        }
        else {
          Alert.alert("Invalid Email address")
        }

      }

    }
  }
  const data = useSelector(state => state.addUser)


  const handleNavigation = () => {
    navigation.navigate('Login')
  }

  const getdata = () => {
    const data = data.filter(item => item.use)
  }

  return (
    <SafeAreaView>

      <KeyboardAwareScrollView>
        <View style={styles.container}>
          <View style={styles.formContainer}>
            <View>
            <Text style={styles.inputLabel}>Name</Text>
              {user ?
                <TextInput placeholder='Enter your name'
                  onChangeText={(e) => setUserData({ ...userData, name: e })}
                  style={styles.inputBox} value={user[0].name}
                />
                :
                <TextInput placeholder='Enter your name'
                    onChangeText={(e) => setUserData({ ...userData, name: e })}
                    style={styles.inputBox}
                  />
                
              }
            </View>
            <View>
              <Text style={styles.inputLabel}> Username </Text>
              {!user ?<TextInput placeholder='create a username'
                onChangeText={(e) => setUserData({ ...userData, username: e })}
                style={styles.inputBox}
              />
            :
            <TextInput placeholder='create a username'
                onChangeText={(e) => setUserData({ ...userData, username: e })}
                style={styles.inputBox} value={user[0].username}
              />}
            </View>
            <View>
              <Text style={styles.inputLabel}> Mobile Number </Text>
              {!user ?
                <TextInput placeholder='Enter your Mobile Number'
                onChangeText={(e) => setUserData({ ...userData, mobile: e })}
                style={styles.inputBox}
                inputMode='tel'
              />
              :
              <TextInput placeholder='Enter your Mobile Number'
                onChangeText={(e) => setUserData({ ...userData, mobile: e })}
                style={styles.inputBox}
                inputMode='tel' value={user[0].mobile}
              />
              }
            </View>
            <View>
              <Text style={styles.inputLabel}> email </Text>
              {!user ?
                <TextInput placeholder='Enter your email'
                onChangeText={(e) => setUserData({ ...userData, email: e })}
                style={styles.inputBox}
                inputMode='email'
              />
              :
              <TextInput placeholder='Enter your email'
                onChangeText={(e) => setUserData({ ...userData, email: e })}
                style={styles.inputBox}
                inputMode='email' value={user[0].email}
              />
              }
            </View>


            <View>
              <Text style={styles.inputLabel}> Address </Text>
              {!user?
                <TextInput placeholder='Enter your Address'
                onChangeText={(e) => setUserData({ ...userData, addres: e })}
                style={styles.inputBox}
              />
              :
              <TextInput placeholder='Enter your Address'
                onChangeText={(e) => setUserData({ ...userData, addres: e })}
                style={styles.inputBox} value={user[0].address}
              />
              }
            </View>

            <View>
              <Text style={styles.inputLabel}> Country </Text>
              <ListModal setCountryData={setCountryData} value="country" countryname={countryData?.name} />
              {/* {countryData &&
                <View style={{ marginVertical: 4, marginHorizontal: 5, }}>
                  <Text style={{ color: 'black', fontSize: 20 }} >{countryData.name}
                  </Text>
                </View>
              } */}
            </View>

            {
              countryData &&
              <View>
                <Text style={styles.inputLabel}> State </Text>
                <ListModal countryId={countryId} setStateData={setStateData}
                  countryname={stateData?.name}
                  value="state" />

                {/* {stateData &&
                  <View style={{ marginVertical: 4, marginHorizontal: 5, }}>
                    <Text style={{ color: 'black', fontSize: 20 }}>{stateData.name}
                    </Text>
                  </View>
                } */}
              </View>
            }

            <View>
              <Text style={styles.inputLabel}>Password </Text>
              <TextInput placeholder='Enter your Password'
                style={styles.inputBox}
                onChangeText={(e) => setUserData({ ...userData, password: e })}
              />
            </View>
            <View>
              <Text style={styles.inputLabel}> Confirm Password </Text>
              <TextInput placeholder='please confirm your Password'
                style={styles.inputBox}
                onChangeText={(e) => setConfirmPassword(e)}
              />
            </View>

            <View style={styles.signupBox}>
              {
                page === "profile" ?
                <TouchableOpacity>
                    <Text style={{ color: 'white' }}
                      onPress={handleSignup}
                    >Update</Text>
                  </TouchableOpacity>
                  
                  :
                  <TouchableOpacity>
                    <Text style={{ color: 'white' }}
                      onPress={handleSignup}
                    >Sign Up</Text>
                  </TouchableOpacity>
                  
              }
            </View>

            {
              !page === 'profile' &&
              <View style={styles.loginBox}>
                <View>
                  <Text style={styles.logintext} >Already have an account ? </Text>
                </View>
                <View >
                  <TouchableOpacity style={styles.loginButton} onPress={handleNavigation}>
                    <Text style={{ color: 'blue' }}  >Sign In</Text>
                  </TouchableOpacity>
                </View>
              </View>}

          </View>



        </View>
      </KeyboardAwareScrollView>


    </SafeAreaView>




Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

Issue
The basic issue is that you have no root state property named "addUser". The addUserSlice slice's name property isn't used when composing/combining reducers to construct the state tree.
With const persistedReducer = persistReducer(persistConfig, addUserSlice); you effectively have a state object with only the userData property, e.g. the state that is the addUserSlice reducer state.
{
  userData: []
}

Solution
Update the persistConfig configuration to whitelist the userData property of the single reducer that forms the state tree.
import { combineReducers, configureStore } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import { persistReducer, persistStore } from "redux-persist";
import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-async-storage/async-storage';
import addUserReducer from "./slices/addUserSlice";

const persistConfig = {
  key: 'root',
  storage: AsyncStorage,
  whitelist: ['userData'],
}

const persistedReducer = persistReducer(persistConfig, addUserReducer);

export const store = configureStore({
  reducer: persistedReducer,
  middleware: (getDefaultMiddleware) => getDefaultMiddleware({
    immutableCheck: false,
    serializableCheck: false,
  })      
});

export const persistor = persistStore(store);

If you plan to add more reducers to the store though you'll need to actually combine reducers, and in this case you'd need to actually provide the state name for each reducer slice you add. For example your code could look something like the following:
import { combineReducers, configureStore } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import { persistReducer, persistStore } from "redux-persist";
import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-async-storage/async-storage';
import addUserReducer from "./slices/addUserSlice";
// ... other reducer imports ...

const persistConfig = {
  key: 'root',
  storage: AsyncStorage,
  whitelist: ['addUser'],
}

const rootReducer = combineReducers({
  addUser: addUserReducer,
  someState: someStateReducer,
  otherState: otherStateReducer,
  // ... etc ...
});

const persistedReducer = persistReducer(persistConfig, rootReducer);

export const store = configureStore({
  reducer: persistedReducer,
  middleware: (getDefaultMiddleware) => getDefaultMiddleware({
    immutableCheck: false,
    serializableCheck: false,
  })      
});

export const persistor = persistStore(store);

Alternatively you could persist just the addUser reducer specifically.
import { combineReducers, configureStore } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import { persistReducer, persistStore } from "redux-persist";
import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-async-storage/async-storage';
import addUserReducer from "./slices/addUserSlice";
// ... other reducer imports ...

const addUserPersistConfig = {
  key: 'adduser',
  storage: AsyncStorage,
}

const persistedAddUserReducer = persistReducer(addUserPersistConfig, addUserReducer);

const rootReducer = combineReducers({
  addUser: persistedAddUserReducer,
  someState: someStateReducer,
  otherState: otherStateReducer,
  // ... etc ...
});

export const store = configureStore({
  reducer: rootReducer,
  middleware: (getDefaultMiddleware) => getDefaultMiddleware({
    immutableCheck: false,
    serializableCheck: false,
  })      
});

export const persistor = persistStore(store);

Additional Tip/Suggestion
You'll likely want to not disable the immutability and serializability checks, they help you find logical issues in your code much earlier in the development flow. If it was Redux-Persist causing some errors/warnings about non-serializable action payloads then you can configure RTK to ignore these specific actions
Example:
import { combineReducers, configureStore } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import {
  persistStore,
  persistReducer,
  FLUSH,
  REHYDRATE,
  PAUSE,
  PERSIST,
  PURGE,
  REGISTER,
} from "redux-persist";
import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-async-storage/async-storage';
import addUserReducer from "./slices/addUserSlice";

const persistConfig = {
  key: 'root',
  storage: AsyncStorage,
  whitelist: ['userData'],
}

const persistedReducer = persistReducer(persistConfig, addUserReducer);

const reduxPersistActions = [FLUSH, REHYDRATE, PAUSE, PERSIST, PURGE, REGISTER];

export const store = configureStore({
  reducer: persistedReducer,
  middleware: (getDefaultMiddleware) => getDefaultMiddleware({
    serializableCheck: {
      ignoredActions: reduxPersistActions,
    },
  })      
});

export const persistor = persistStore(store);

See Immutability Middleware and Serializability Middleware for further details on customization over completely disabling the checks.
